# Which VMs or GCs support JNI pinning?

Tags: java, java-native-interface

`Get<PrimitiveType>ArrayElements` family of functions are documented to either copy arrays, or pin them in place (and, in so doing, prevent a compacting garbage collector from moving them). It is documented as a safer, less-restrictive alternative to `GetPrimitiveArrayCritical`. However, I'd like to know which VMs and/or garbage collectors (if any) actually pin arrays instead of copying them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

G1 supports pinning as of Java 22: https://openjdk.org/jeps/423

Shenandoah supports pinning as of Java 15: https://shipilev.net/jvm-anatomy-park/9-jni-critical-gclocker/

In both cases it's not clear if pinning happens when using `Get*ArrayElements` or only when `Get*Critical`.

Both GCs pin memory regions and not individual objects, so if very many regions are pinned the effect may turn out to be the same as if no pinning is done.

Answer (score 11):

Older IBM JVMs pinned (1.4 and before - ie: NOT the current IBM J9 JVM) but since then, they have not. In general, JVMs don't like pinning as it really messes up copying garbage collectors, which is what most production JVMs do today. I'm not 100% up to date (ie: latest Java 7 builds), but historically HotSpot didn't either (for the same generational GC reasons).

Be aware: a JVM that pins today might not tomorrow, and vice versa, so you need to write your code to handle it both ways, just like the base Java libraries do.