# Understanding safe access of JNI arguments

Tags: java, c++, c, jvm, java-native-interface

I'm doing some research regarding how HotSpot performs garbage-collection and/or heap-compaction while JNI code is running.

It appears to be common knowledge that objects could be moved at any time in Java.  I'm trying to understand, definitively if JNI is subject to effects garbage-collection.  There exist a number of JNI functions to explicitly prevent garbage-collection; such as `GetPrimitiveArrayCritical`.  It makes sense that such a function exists if the references are indeed volatile.  However, it makes no sense if they are not.

There seems to be a substantial amount of conflicting information on this subject and I'm trying to sort it out.

> JNI code runs in a safepoint and can continue running, unless it calls
> back into Java or calls some specific JVM methods, at which point it
> may be stopped to prevent leaving the safepoint (thanks Nitsan for the
> comments).
>
> [What mechanism JVM use to block threads during stop-the-world pause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16558746/what-mechanism-jvm-use-to-block-threads-during-stop-the-world-pause)

The above makes me think that garbage-collection is going to run concurrently with JNI code.  That can't be safe, right?

> To implement local references, the Java VM creates a registry for each
> transition of control from Java to a native method. A registry maps
> nonmovable local references to Java objects, and keeps the objects
> from being garbage collected. All Java objects passed to the native
> method (including those that are returned as the results of JNI
> function calls) are automatically added to the registry. The registry
> is deleted after the native method returns, allowing all of its
> entries to be garbage collected.
>
> https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/design.html#wp16789

Okay, so the `local` references are nonmovable but that doesn't say anything about the compaction.

> The JVM must ensure that objects passed as parameters from Java™ to
> the native method and any new objects created by the native code
> remain reachable by the GC. To handle the GC requirements, the JVM
> allocates a small region of specialized storage called a "local
> reference root set".
>
> A local reference root set is created when:
>
> - A thread is first attached to the JVM (the "outermost" root set of the thread).
> - Each J2N transition occurs.
>
> The JVM initializes the root set created for a J2N transition with:
>
> - A local reference to the caller's object or class.
> - A local reference to each object passed as a parameter to the native method.
>
> New local references created in native code are added to this J2N root
> set, unless you create a new "local frame" using the PushLocalFrame
> JNI function.
>
> http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSYKE2_5.0.0/com.ibm.java.doc.diagnostics.50/diag/understanding/jni_transitions_j2n.html

Okay, so *IBM* stores the passed objects in the `local reference root set` but it doesn't discuss about memory compaction.  This just says that the objects won't be garbage-collected.

> The GC might, at any time, decide it needs to compact the
> garbage-collected heap. Compaction involves physically moving objects
> from one address to another. These objects might be referred to by a
> JNI local or global reference. To allow compaction to occur safely,
> JNI references are not direct pointers to the heap. At least one level
> of indirection isolates the native code from object movement.
>
> If a native method needs to obtain direct addressability to the inside
> of an object, the situation is more complicated. The requirement to
> directly address, or pin, the heap is typical where there is a need
> for fast, shared access to large primitive arrays. An example might
> include a screen buffer. In these cases a JNI critical section can be
> used, which imposes additional requirements on the programmer, as
> specified in the JNI description for these functions. See the JNI
> specification for details.
>
> - GetPrimitiveArrayCritical returns the direct heap address of a Java™ array, disabling garbage collection until the corresponding
>   ReleasePrimitiveArrayCritical is called.
> - GetStringCritical returns the direct heap address of a java.lang.String instance, disabling garbage collection until ReleaseStringCritical is called.
>
> http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSYKE2_6.0.0/com.ibm.java.doc.diagnostics.60/diag/understanding/jni_copypin.html

Okay, so *IBM* basically says that the JNI passed objects COULD be moved at any time!  How about *HotSpot*?

> GetArrayElements family of functions are documented to
> either copy arrays, or pin them in place (and, in so doing, prevent a
> compacting garbage collector from moving them). It is documented as a
> safer, less-restrictive alternative to GetPrimitiveArrayCritical.
> However, I'd like to know which VMs and/or garbage collectors (if any)
> actually pin arrays instead of copying them.
>
> [Which VMs or GCs support JNI pinning?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21175443/which-vms-or-gcs-support-jni-pinning)

**Aleksandr** seems to think that the only safe way to access the memory of passed objects is through `Get<PrimitiveType>ArrayElements` or `GetPrimitiveArrayCritical`

**Trent's** answer was less than exciting.

> At least in current JVM's (i have not checked to see how far back this
> was backported), CMS GC, since it's non-moving is not affected by JNI
> critical sections (modulo that non stop-worl compaction can occur if
> there is a concurrent mode failure -- in that case the allocating
> thread must stall until the critical section is cleared -- this latter
> kind of stall is likely to be much rarer than the slow-path direct
> allocation in old gen pathology that you might see more frequently).
> Note that direct allocation in old gen is not only slow in and of
> itself (a first-order performance impact) but can in turn cause more
> tenuring (because of so-called nepotism), as well as slower subsequent
> scavenges because of more direty cards needing scanning (both of the
> latter being second-rder effects).
>
> http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/hotspot-runtime-dev/2007-December/000074.html

This email on the OpenJDK mailing list seems to say that the ConcurrentMarkAndSweep GC is non-moving.

> https://www.infoq.com/articles/G1-One-Garbage-Collector-To-Rule-Them-All

This post about G1 mentions that it does compact the heap but not much specifically about moving data.

---

Since the IBM documentation alludes to the fact that the objects could be compacted at any time; we need to figure out WHY the JNI HotSpot functions are actually safe at all. Right, because they must need to move to a safe state to prevent the concurrent memory effects if memory-compaction is indeed happening while the JNI code is running.

Now, I've been following the HotSpot code the best I can.  Lets take a look at `GetByteArrayElements`.  It seems logical that the method must ensure that the pointer is correct before copying the elements.  Lets try to find out how.

Here is the macro for `GetByteArrayElements`

```
#ifndef USDT2
#define DEFINE_GETSCALARARRAYELEMENTS(ElementTag,ElementType,Result, Tag) 
JNI_QUICK_ENTRY(ElementType*,
          jni_Get##Result##ArrayElements(JNIEnv *env, ElementType##Array array, jboolean *isCopy))
  JNIWrapper("Get" XSTR(Result) "ArrayElements");
  DTRACE_PROBE3(hotspot_jni, Get##Result##ArrayElements__entry, env, array, isCopy);
  /* allocate an chunk of memory in c land */
  typeArrayOop a = typeArrayOop(JNIHandles::resolve_non_null(array));
  ElementType* result;
  int len = a->length();
  if (len == 0) {
    result = (ElementType*)get_bad_address();
  } else {
    result = NEW_C_HEAP_ARRAY_RETURN_NULL(ElementType, len, mtInternal);
    if (result != NULL) {                                    
          memcpy(result, a->Tag##_at_addr(0), sizeof(ElementType)*len);
      if (isCopy) {
        *isCopy = JNI_TRUE;
      }
    }  
  }
  DTRACE_PROBE1(hotspot_jni, Get##Result##ArrayElements__return, result);
  return result;
JNI_END
```

Here is the macro for `JNI_QUICK_ENTRY`

```
#define JNI_QUICK_ENTRY(result_type, header)                         \
extern "C" {                                                         \
  result_type JNICALL header {                                \
    JavaThread* thread=JavaThread::thread_from_jni_environment(env); \
    assert( !VerifyJNIEnvThread || (thread == Thread::current()), "JNIEnv is only valid in same thread"); \
    ThreadInVMfromNative __tiv(thread);                              \
    debug_only(VMNativeEntryWrapper __vew;)                          \
VM_QUICK_ENTRY_BASE(result_type, header, thread)
```

I have followed every function in here and yet have to see any kind of mutex or memory synchronizer.  The only function I could not follow was `__tiv` which does not seem to have a definition anywhere I could find.

- **Could someone explain to me why JNI interface methods such as `GetByteArrayElements` are safe?**
- **While we're at it, can anyone find where the JNI call transitions from VM back to Native when `JNI_QUICK_ENTRY` exits?**

Comment: “*Since the IBM documentation alludes to the fact that the objects could be compacted at any time; we need to figure out WHY the JNI HotSpot functions are actually safe at all*” — You know that IBM’s JVM and HotSpot are two entirely different implementations?

Comment: Yes they are.  But that does not mean similarities don't exist.  The information about the IBM VM is to provide additional context.

Comment: Everything you need to know is contained in the [JNI Specification 'Referencing Java Objects'](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/design.html#referencing_java_objects) section. This defines what you must do and what the JVM must do. All implementations must comply. Don't worry about what else Sun or Oracle or IBM or any other vendor may say, and don't confuse yourself with cherry-picking from StackOverflow answers or other third-party resources.

Comment: @user207421 I was looking for greater understanding because I wanted to do something very very unsafe and non-portable for performance reasons.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### How JNI methods work in HotSpot JVM

1. Native methods may run concurrently with VM operations including GC. They are [not stopped at safepoints](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39209068/does-jvm-halt-when-calling-native-code/39211887#39211887).
2. GC may move Java objects even if they are referenced from a running native method. `jobject` handle is not a raw address into the heap, but rather one more level of indirection: consider it a pointer into a non-movable array of object references. Whenever an object is moved, the corresponding array slot is updated, but the pointer to this slot remains the same. That is, `jobject` handle remains valid.
   Every time a native method calls a JNI function, it checks if JVM is in the safepoint state. If it is (e.g. GC is running), JNI function blocks until safepoint operation is completed.
3. During the execution of JNI functions like `GetByteArrayElements`, the corresponding thread is marked as [`_thread_in_vm`](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8u/jdk8u/hotspot/file/312e113bc3ed/src/share/vm/utilities/globalDefinitions.hpp#l852). A safepoint cannot be reached while there are running threads in this state. E.g. if GC is requested during the execution of `GetByteArrayElements`, GC will be delayed until JNI function returns.
4. Thread state transition magic is performed by the line you've noticed:
   `ThreadInVMfromNative __tiv(thread)`. Here `__tiv` is just an instance of the class. Its only purpose is to automatically call `ThreadInVMfromNative` constructor and destructor.

   [`ThreadInVMfromNative`](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8u/jdk8u/hotspot/file/a753c8401458/src/share/vm/runtime/interfaceSupport.hpp#l277) constructor calls [`transition_from_native`](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8u/jdk8u/hotspot/file/a753c8401458/src/share/vm/runtime/interfaceSupport.hpp#l199) which [checks](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8u/jdk8u/hotspot/file/a753c8401458/src/share/vm/runtime/interfaceSupport.hpp#l219) for a  safepoint, and suspends current thread if needed. [`~ThreadInVMfromNative`](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8u/jdk8u/hotspot/file/a753c8401458/src/share/vm/runtime/interfaceSupport.hpp#l280) destructor switches back to `_thread_in_native` state.
5. `GetPrimitiveArrayCritical` and `GetStringCritical` are the only JNI functions that provide raw pointers to Java heap. They [prevent GC from starting](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8u/jdk8u/hotspot/file/a753c8401458/src/share/vm/memory/gcLocker.hpp#l127) until the corresponding `Release` function is called.

#### Thread state transition when calling a JNI function from native code

1. **state = _thread_in_native;**
   Native method may run concurrently with GC
2. JNI function is called
3. **state = _thread_in_native_trans;**
   GC cannot start at this point
4. If VM operation is in progress, block until it completes
5. **state = _thread_in_vm;**
   Safe to access heap

Comment: This also brings up WHY JNI calls are expensive; releasing the in_vm lock an re-obtaiing it when the JNI returns is expensive.  If we could write JNI code that was considered in_vm then it would be so much faster.

Comment: why cannot safepoint be reached in vm state?  Is there something special performed in that state, which may affect gc operation?

Comment: @choxsword While `_thread_in_vm`, JVM may access heap with raw pointers

Answer (score 2):

> It appears to be common knowledge that objects could be moved at any time.

It may be common, but it isn't knowledge, and it isn't true. Objects passed to or held by JNI methods are not available for movement until the method returns, or the object is explicitly released, or the LocalFrame containing it is popped.

> If this was true, then every JNI interface method must require a lock or some kind of memory synchronization?

No, see above.

Comment: Right, this doc https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/design.html#wp16789 says just that but there is a lot of mixed signals. Maybe I've been doing too much searching.

Comment: That would mean that JNI methods such as GetXXXCrtiical are only useful or necessary for accessing objects referenced in the passed arguments?

Comment: You don't need to worry about what anyone says if it is contradicted by the specification. `GetXXXCritical()` ['make it more likely that the native code will obtain an uncopied version of the array'](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/functions.html#GetPrimitiveArrayCritical). Nothing to do with 'objects referenced in the passed arguments'.

Comment: What's the point of `GetXXXCritical` which actually calls `GC_locke::lock_critical(thread)` and seems like a more expensive operation than regular JNI?

Comment: I just answered that.

Comment: Well, reading the bytes directly out of the object pointer will not copy anything so wouldn't that make it moot?

Comment: All I'm doing here is quoting from the documentation. You need to look at the discussion of pinning. It's all in there.

Comment: I rewrote the entire question; you should look at it.

Comment: *"Objects passed to or held by JNI methods are not available for movement until the method returns"* - Wrong. HotSpot JVM can move Java objects referenced from running JNI methods. However, `jobject` handles still remain valid, because they are not direct references to the heap.

Comment: “*All I'm doing here is quoting from the documentation*”—shouldn’t a quote be marked as such and augmented with a link to the source?

Comment: @Holger Every such quotation **is** in the form of a link. What are you talking about?

Comment: @apangin You are arguing with the JNI Speification here, not me.

Comment: @EJP: your answer doesn’t contain any link, but the strong claim “*Objects passed to or held by JNI methods are not available for movement…*”, which is not backed by anything.