# JVM crash without leaving any log

Tags: java, jvm

I'm a newbie in java application debugging, still, try to learn a various aspect of java application debugging. I have a windows application comprises of many jar file & executed by a single .exe file written in c++. The application works smoothly but after a certain time of usage, it crashes

> (Java (TM) Platform SE binary is not responding)

leaving no log. I tried -XX:ErrorFile argument but it does not generate any error file. I have also tried heap-dump analysis but it also shows no memory leak. Can anyone please tell me what could be the possible reason for the JVM crash! Or how can I get the log file of the crash?

At the ideal time, the application consumes only 1-10% of CPU & 250-280MB Memory but after the crash, it sticks to 25% of CPU usage & 250-280MB Memory usage. I dedicated 2048M of Memory to this application.

Thread dump shows following thread before the application hang

```
"Thread-1" #12 daemon prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x0000000018392800 nid=0x2de0 waiting on condition [0x0000000018ece000]
java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (parking)
at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
- parking to wait for  <0x00000000a1da8db8> (a java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject)
at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:175)
at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2039)
at java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingDeque.takeFirst(LinkedBlockingDeque.java:492)
at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:108)

Locked ownable synchronizers:
- None
```

After the application hang the same thread is changed to -

```
"Thread-1" #12 daemon prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x0000000018392800 nid=0x2de0 in Object.wait() [0x0000000018ece000]
java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (on object monitor)
at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:502)
at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:126)
- locked <0x00000000a1d65960> (a java.lang.StringBuilder)

Locked ownable synchronizers:
- None
```

How can I solve the issue?

Thread dump file link - [Thread Dump File Link](https://www.sendspace.com/file/sdqv30)
[image: JMC Threads]

Comment: You should add more details what has happened. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44062332/jvm-crashes-when-calling-jni-function-during-gc

Comment: Thank you to trying to help me. Actually I don't know much details about java but I can send the file to you through mail or if possible DM. I can't share the link in public.

Comment: "JVM crashes" is not the same as "JVM is not responding consuming 25% CPU (presumably 1 core)".

Comment: Obviously JVM did not crash - it seems to get into a busy loop. You need to find what it is busy with. Start with `jstack` or `jstack -m`.

Comment: I have done a thread dump but I actually don't know how to read it. If anyone please guide me where is the problem. Zip has both before & after the JVM crash. Here is the link of the thread dump [Link](https://www52.zippyshare.com/v/9wn0o7ii/file.html)

Comment: I don't see zip file at the link above - only lots of ads and malware.

Comment: Here is another link [Link](https://www.sendspace.com/file/sdqv30)